# Flask - how to redirect after fetch post

Tags: javascript, python, flask, redirect, fetch

Currently I have a search page that takes input then uses it to search an api for data. I post the input from the page to the server like so

```
fetch('/search', {  
            method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),  
            body: JSON.stringify({data: input,token: token,})
        })
        .then(function (data) {  
            console.log('Request success: ', data);  
        })  
        .catch(function (error) {  
            console.log('Request failure: ', error);  
        });
```

The input on the server is set like so

```
req = request.get_json()
input = req['data']
```

The `input` from above is then used to search and return a result. I need to use the `server side result` to determine where to redirect the user. I would have gone with something like `window.location.href = '/search/bad'` to redirect but I don't know whether or not the search is good until the `result.is_success()/error()` below

```
if result.is_success():
  print('search was success ',result.body)
  return redirect(url_for('search_bad'))
elif result.is_error():
  print('search was failure ',result.errors)
  return redirect(url_for('search_bad'))
```

What I see in the terminal is

```
search was failure  ....
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2020 14:33:54] "POST /search HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2020 14:33:54] "GET /search/bad HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I thought about simply using a form but from the fetch post above there's also token used in the search. I don't understand why the redirect doesn't work, it just sits there on the search page. There's a 200 response `/search/bad HTTP/1.1" 200` but it doesn't go/redirect to the bad search url. Any ideas on how to get the redirect to work?

Answer (score 2):

If other guys also face that same issue, this is how I solved  =>

Python file

```
flash('some message for index page')  
return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

At Javascript

```
fetch('url',{
    method:'POST'                
    }) 
    .then((response)=>{         
        if(response.redirected){
            window.location.href = response.url;
        }
    })           
    .catch(function(e){
        
    })
```

So it will load the index page with the message.

Comment: The response from @farvilain is useful as an explanation. However, I wanted to control the content of the data. This solution works, appears 'clean' and It seems to me that it is better suited to my needs than a form submit.  Thanks for providing it!

Comment: This response is actually suggested in Flask's documentation, with other useful information:  https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/patterns/javascript#following-redirects

Answer (score 1):

A server redirection is not a browser redirection. The redirection will just cause the fetch/curl to request the new url (if configured, like `-F` in curl)

What about using something like that?

If the search is 'invalid', the server returns a statusCode 400.
On the client, if the search response has a status 400, then `window.location.href = '/search/bad'`

Our you can use a real `<form>` to submit a real http POST by the browser (not by fetch or any js client). On this case, redirection will be followed by browser.