# Redirect function from Flask doesn't work at all

Tags: python, flask, web3py

I'm developing a Flask app and at the moment everything works fine, but I'm unable to redirect the browser to the desired page. I can't even redirect to an external URL.

In the page /proposals there's a button which calls a JavaScript login function:

```
let provider;
let accounts;

let accountAddress = "";
let signer;

function submit_proposal() {
  console.log("oh hey there");

  // signer.signMessage("hello");

  rightnow = (Date.now() / 1000).toFixed(0);
  sortanow = rightnow - (rightnow % 600);

  signer
    .signMessage(
      "Signing in to transparency.smartindex.cash at " + sortanow,
      accountAddress,
      "test password!"
    )
    .then((signature) => {
      handleAuth(accountAddress, signature);
    });
}

function handleAuth(accountAddress, signature) {
  console.log(accountAddress);
  console.log(signature);

  fetch("login", {
    method: "post",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify([accountAddress, signature]),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
}

ethereum.enable().then(function () {
  provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(web3.currentProvider);

  provider.getNetwork().then(function (result) {
    if (result["chainId"] != 10000) {
      document.getElementById("msg").textContent = "Switch to SmartBCH!";
    } else {
      // okay, confirmed we're on mainnet

      provider.listAccounts().then(async function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        accountAddress = result[0]; // getting uesrs publickey

        // contract address and contract abi is used to create the contract instance
        const contractAddress = "0xF05bD3d7709980f60CD5206BddFFA8553176dd29";
        const contractABI = [
          // balanceOf
          {
            constant: true,
            inputs: [{ name: "_owner", type: "address" }],
            name: "balanceOf",
            outputs: [{ name: "balance", type: "uint256" }],
            type: "function",
          },
          // decimals
          {
            constant: true,
            inputs: [],
            name: "decimals",
            outputs: [{ name: "", type: "uint8" }],
            type: "function",
          },
        ];

        // creating contract instance
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(
          contractAddress,
          contractABI,
          provider
        );

        // getting the contract decimals and balance
        const decimals = await contract.decimals();
        let balance = await contract.balanceOf(accountAddress);
        balance = parseFloat(ethers.utils.formatUnits(balance, decimals));

        if (balance < 5000) {
          // if SIDX  balance < 5000, insufficient balance
          document.getElementById("msg").textContent =
            "You need at least 5000 SIDX tokens to submit a proposal";
        } else {
          // else allow user to submit proposal
          const submitProposalButton =
            document.getElementById("submit_proposal");
          submitProposalButton.disabled = false;
          signer = provider.getSigner();
        }
      });
    }
  });
})
```

This is the Flask function which handles the login and tries to redirect to /submit_proposal:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('submit_proposal'))
    w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://smartbch.greyh.at'))
    if not w3.isConnected():
        w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://smartbch.fountainhead.cash/mainnet'))

    public_address = request.json[0]
    signature = request.json[1]

    domain = "transparency.smartindex.cash"

    rightnow = int(time.time())
    sortanow = rightnow - rightnow % 600

    original_message = 'Signing in to {} at {}'.format(domain, sortanow)
    message_hash = defunct_hash_message(text=original_message)
    signer = w3.eth.account.recoverHash(message_hash, signature=signature)

    if signer == public_address:
        ABI = open("/home/administrador/Descargas/BCH/transparency_portal/ABIs/ERC20-ABI.json", "r")  # Standard ABI for ERC20 tokens
        abi = json.loads(ABI.read())
        contract = w3.eth.contract(address="0xF05bD3d7709980f60CD5206BddFFA8553176dd29", abi=abi)
        SIDX_balance = contract.functions.balanceOf(signer).call() / 10 ** 18
        if SIDX_balance < 5000:
            flash('You need at least 5000 SIDX token to submit a proposal')
            return url_for('proposals')
        else:
            if db.session.query(Users).filter(Users.public_address == signer).first() is None:
                user = Users(public_address=signer)
                db.session.add(user)
                db.session.commit()
            user = Users.query.filter_by(public_address=signer).first()
            login_user(user)
            # return redirect(url_for('submit_proposal'))
    else:
        abort(401, 'Could not authenticate signature')
    return redirect(url_for('submit_proposal'))
```

Despite the redirects fails, I get this message in the console:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Dec/2021 15:47:09] "GET /submit_proposal HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

The user is logged correctly (I've check it), so I can manually so to /submit_proposal.

This is the /submit_proposal view:

```
@app.route('/submit_proposal')
@login_required
def submit_proposal():
    with open('data/SIDX_STATS.json') as sidx_stats_file:
        sidx_stats = json.load(sidx_stats_file)
    print(request)
    return render_template("submit_proposal.html", title="Submit a proposal", sidx_stats=sidx_stats)
```

Request output is <Request 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/submit_proposal' [GET]>.
It seems to be correct, but the browser does nothing. Even I tried to just redirect to an external page, but again, browser does nothing. This is not the first time I cannot get redirect to work, so I guess that the error is not on the login function.

**EDIT:**

Please, someone with some JavaScript knowledge can guide me to do something like this?

```
function submit_proposal() {
  console.log("oh hey there");

  // signer.signMessage("hello");

  rightnow = (Date.now() / 1000).toFixed(0);
  sortanow = rightnow - (rightnow % 600);

  signer
    .signMessage(
      "Signing in to transparency.smartindex.cash at " + sortanow,
      accountAddress,
      "test password!"
    )
    .then((signature) => {
      handleAuth(accountAddress, signature);
    })
    .then((response)=>{
        if(response.redirected){
            window.location.href = response.url;
        }
    })
    .catch(function(e){
    })
}
```

What I'm trying to do is, once the function submit_proposal is called, wait for a server response with the redirection.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64636415/flask-how-to-redirect-after-fetch-post Try this solution

Comment: @KeeganM Thank you for your help. I'll try to implement the solution described there using the window.location.href. I have no idea of JavaScript, but my idea is that once the submit_proposal function is called, wait for the server to submit the url.